# Class Template Object cannot be created

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I am using templates in one of my classes, but for some reason, when i create an object, the error i am getting is the following: Argument list for class template "Test" is missing.

```
template <class T>
class Test
{
 private: 
     T variable;

 public:
     Test(){cout << "CONSTRUCTOR CALLED" << endl;}
};
```

in main.cpp

```
Test object;
```

Compiler displays the following: 'Test' : use of class template requires template argument list.

```
template <class T>
Test<T>::Test() 
{
  cout << "CONSTRUCTOR CALLED" << endl;
}
```

That also did not work

Comment: If your class uses templates, you're supposed to give it template parameters (or arguments) when you try to use it (i.e. `Test<int> object;`)

Comment: You need to paramaterize it with a type, like `Test<int> object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the type you want to instantiate a `class template`.
for example:

```
  Test<int> object;
```

Think about how you use class templates from `std library` like `vectors`,
you have to specify the type such as `int`, e.g. `vector<int>` . This is the same rationale like that.

For constructor definition, it should work, however, one point is that you have to put declaration and definition in the same header file, otherwise, compiler cannot find the definition. (There are techniques that you can separate declaration and definition in different files, like "export" and "#include cpp file" at end of header file)